# Visual Studio 2017 is debugging in a new window instead of a new tab and Stops debugging if i close that window

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have just reinstalled Visual Studio 2017 enterprise edition and have ran into a strange problem.

When I debug in Chrome it opens a new window instead of a new tab and if i then either close the window or try to move that tab into my other window Visual Studio stops debugging.

I have checked to see if the "Enable JavaScript Debugging for ASP.Net (Chrome, Edge and IE)" is checked and it is not.

Does anyone know what would be causing this as it is very annoying and slowing down my work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck also Enabled and Edit Continue checkbox.

This should solve closing issue but I couldnt find way to open in new tab instead of window yet.

Comment: Found it !  
Also disable Tools -> Options -> Project and Solutions -> Web Projects: "Stop debugger when browser window is closed".

Comment: @Tempus Where is the "Enabled and Edit Continue" checkbox?